# Cannot create a new account in front end of 1.9.2.3

Tags: ce-1.9.2.3

I understand there is a standard fix for resolving the inability to create an account in the Magento frontend.  Per this fix:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/Upgraded-to1-9-2-2-from-1-9-1-1-and-now-user-registration-not/m-p/20438#U20438

I have applied the fix as recommended to the four appropriate files, cleared cache and sessions, cleared browser cache as well. I am on 1.9.2.3

I still cannot get Magento to create the new customer account.  It just clears the screen back to the create account page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It is dependent on your theme, and possibly parent themes. So, it's important to make sure that the /app/design/frontend/base, /app/design/frontend/default, and /app/design/frontend/yourtheme are all updated. If your theme is inheriting from either the rwd or base, it would work, but if your theme has included these files as well, it will use them in the place of the default. If you use a custom theme, don't just replace the files – they may be different. Instead, add the formkey.

Comment: It appears I have all the directory files you indicated updated.  I did however notice there is a RWD directory and in that the register.phtml file was missing in the ../customer/form directory.  BTW I've been editing the files, not replacing them as you indicated.

Comment: Still, however the issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 2):

So it appears that the fix for my situation is this:

Find these files:

app\design\frontend\THEME\default\template\opc\customer\form\register.phtml

app\design\frontend\THEME\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml

app\design\frontend\THEME\default\template\customer\form\register.phtml

The following code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
```

and change it to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Applied these changes and creating an account now works.

Thanks to those that offered a solution.